# How do I automatically get date and time when status of a task is changed?

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

How do I capture date and time when status of task is changed?

I have 3 different columns `Date Assigned`, `Date In Progress`, `Date Completed`.

When a task is assigned to a user, is there a way `Date assigned` column gets the date & time automatically? If yes, how do we do?

Similarly when user changes task to `In Progress` state, `Date In Progress` should get date & time & similarly when task `is closed` by user, `Date Completed` column should get the time-stamp, so that I can calculate time taken for each task and status in between.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I thought I'd put what we do, since we do this a lot. We add a CEWP to the EditForm.js page with the requisite script references

```
var todayFormat = new Date().format('MM/dd/yyyy');
$("select[title='Task Status']").change(function() {
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'In Progress': {
            $('input[title="Date In Progress"]').val(todayFormat);
            break;
            }
        case 'Needs Edits': {

                break;
        }

    }

});
```

For when a task is assigned, I do that through a Designer workflow. I add a LastAssignedTo field to the list, and mark it as a hidden field. Then, in workflow I can test to see if the assigned to field has changed.

```
if currentitem:assignedTo is not equal to currentitem:lastassignedto
     email
     then set currentitem:assignedDate equal to Today
     then set currentitem:lastassigned equal to currentitem:assignedTo
```

You could also do your dates in a workflow as well instead of javascript - you'd need to add another hidden field to your list - LastStatus, for example, and do something like this to test whether the status field has changed:

```
if currentitem:taskStatus is not equal to currentitem:LastStatus
     if currentitem:taskStatus is equal to 'In Progress'
         set currentitem:DateInProgress equal to Today
     then set currentitem:laststatus equal to currentitem:taskstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [item event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502%28v=office.14%29.aspx), something like this:

```
   public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
      if(properties.BeforeProperties["Status"]!=properties.AfterProperties ["Status"]){
         properties.ListItem["Date In Progress"]=DateTime.Now;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Let's add some null checks to the Before and After properties too

Answer (score -1):

You can also achieve it using Out of Box Nintex Workflow.
Just Add an App > Nintex Workflow.

Create **new Variable** of type Date/Time.
Assign it value when created by configuring **Set Workflow Variable**.
Assign that variable to any column of your list